# How to write this equality sign in asp.net web form?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, equality, symbols, mathjax

I would like to write and equals sign which has a question mark above. How can I write this symbol in my asp.net web form?

From what I understand the language used is MathJax. How can I use MathJax language in my webform?

```
$\stackrel{?}=$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code inside your `<head>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
```

Then write or paste any MathJax expressions and they should appear on your page.

By default, MathJax uses `$$` and `\\` and delimiters.

Add this in the `<head>` tag to use single delimiters instead of double:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
```

This addition will also keep you MathJax codes in line with your existing text. Otherwise, you may experience offsetting and weird positioning of your MathJax code.